# Java Calendar/Timestamp add issue

Tags: java, calendar, timezone

I'm trying to add 4 hours consecutively on a java.sql.Timestamp.
Here the code:

```
Timestamp period = Timestamp.valueOf("2011-10-01 00:00:00");
Timestamp finish = Timestamp.valueOf("2011-12-31 00:00:00");

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

while (period.before(finish)) {
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(period.getTime());
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);
    period.setTime(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    System.out.println(period);
}
```

The output should be a list of Timestamps like:

```
2011-10-02 00:00:00.0
2011-10-02 04:00:00.0
2011-10-02 08:00:00.0
2011-10-02 12:00:00.0
2011-10-02 16:00:00.0
2011-10-02 20:00:00.0
2011-10-03 00:00:00.0
2011-10-03 04:00:00.0
2011-10-03 08:00:00.0
2011-10-03 12:00:00.0
2011-10-03 16:00:00.0
2011-10-03 20:00:00.0
2011-10-04 00:00:00.0
```

It works until reachs 2011-10-30 where are added 3 hours instead 4:

```
2011-10-29 08:00:00.0
2011-10-29 12:00:00.0
2011-10-29 16:00:00.0
2011-10-29 20:00:00.0
2011-10-30 00:00:00.0
2011-10-30 03:00:00.0
2011-10-30 07:00:00.0
2011-10-30 11:00:00.0
2011-10-30 15:00:00.0
2011-10-30 19:00:00.0
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried different dates, like some time in June?  Could this be a daylight savings issue?

Comment: only 30 october 2011 creates this bug but I need this date

Comment: That's not a bug. The calendar works alright. Oct 30 was the switch day in 2011 for daylight saving time. https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2011.html

Comment: so how can i solve this?

Comment: You can't solve time.

Comment: As Matt indicated, its not a bug.

Comment: :| I means avoid DST

Comment: If you just want to have the 4hours difference effect (without daylight saving time changes) use calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

Comment: With TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC") the issue persists

Comment: if you don't mind setting UTC as default Timezone on your program try adding these 2 commands at the very beginning System.setProperty("user.timezone", "UTC");
TimeZone.setDefault(null); - otherwise, you need to use a DateFormat with timezone to print as expected

Comment: It Works!! Thanks a lot @KonstantinosChalkias